# Create Lookalike audience using Facebook API

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a Lookalike Audience using Facebook API. This my code:

```
public override SocialAudience CreateCustomAudience(SocialAudience SAudience)
{
    string access_token = GetAccessToken(SAudience.AdAccount.FacebookUser);
    FC.AccessToken = access_token;
    dynamic PostParam = new ExpandoObject();
    PostParam.name = SAudience.Audience.Name;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SAudience.Audience.Description))
        PostParam.description = SAudience.Audience.Description;
    dynamic Result = null;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SAudience.Social_ID))
    {
        PostParam.subtype = SAudience.Type;
        if (SAudience.Type.ToUpper() == "LOOKALIKE")
        {
            PostParam.origin_audience_id = SAudience.origin_audience_id;
            PostParam.lookalike_spec = "{ starting_ratio: \"0\", ratio: \"0.01\", location_spec: { geo_locations: { countries: ['UK'] } } }";
        }                
        Result = FC.Post(string.Format("/{0}/customaudiences?fields=id,approximate_count,delivery_status,operation_status", SAudience.AdAccount.Social_ID), PostParam);
        SAudience.Social_ID = Result.id;
    }
    else
        Result = FC.Post(string.Format("/{0}?fields=id,approximate_count,delivery_status,operation_status", SAudience.Social_ID), PostParam);

    SAudience.delivery_status_Description = Result.delivery_status.description;
    SAudience.delivery_status = Result.delivery_status.code.ToString();
    SAudience.Size = Result.approximate_count;
    SAudience.Availability = Result.operation_status.description;
    return SAudience;
}
```

This method create to type of Audience, Custom and lookalike. When i try to create a lookalike audience with this code I get an error:

> (#2654) No Valid Locations Found: Please add valid locations in the
>   location spec.

I change this part of code:

```
PostParam.lookalike_spec = "{ starting_ratio: \"0\", ratio: \"0.01\", location_spec: { geo_locations: { countries: ['UK'] } } }";
```

by:

```
PostParam.lookalike_spec = "{ type: \"reach\", country: \"UK\" }";
```

I get this error:

> (#2654) creating a lookalike audience on country UK is not supported
>   because active user size of is too small

NB: I use a custom audience that has 900 as size.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. I should not use UK code to select United Kingdom people. The correct code is GB.